# How to use "WHERE" with grails criteria

Tags: grails, criteria

```
Class Vote {
       String name;
       Date startDate;
    Date endDate;
    }
```

***I want to show all vote when Date of end is superior to new Date***

Comment: You really should be reading the user guide: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/index.html

Answer (score 1):

[Grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) show you the list of operators in a criteria. In your case you can use `gt` and pass the current date.

```
def votes = Vote.createCriteria().list() {
  gt('endDate', new Date())
}
```